# Append to Grid Items on Drag and Drop

Tags: extjs

I was wondering if there was a way to Append Records to a Grid on a Drop from Dragging an item from another Grid instead of having the user being able to Drop it anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html

Comment: But that example still allows me to drop my record anywhere onto either grid. I'd like to always constrain it to being appended to the items in the grid no matter where I drop the record.

Comment: Ok, you want the record always at the bottom if appended?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. And if there were still a way to drag and drop items within the Grid, that would be definitely be a plus as well

Comment: There is an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/oue